# Rotating indexes in a given list according to a user input, while the sequence of rotation is derived from indexes from another list

Tags: python

This problem is from the ACM ICPC MidCentral 2014 problem set. Specifically, it is problem G, ReverseRot.

I have to write a program which takes a user inputted string, reverses it, and then rotates it according to a list containing the uppercase alphabet from A to Z, underscore, and period.  So far, I've been able to do everything but rotate it correctly. This is the code I have thus far:

```
#character list which is referenced during the rotation
rotationList = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "_", "."] 
reverseRotList = [] #list which stores the completed rotation, later to be joined into a string

def reverse(string) : #reverses the string and stores each character in indexes within a list
    string = string[::-1]
    string = list(string)
    return string

string = input("What is the string? ").upper()
print(reverse(string)) #to show string was reversed and converted into a list correctly

rotAmount = int(input("Amount to be rotated? ")) #user decides how much rotation there will be

for i in string:
```

How would I rotate the string list according to the user input while rotating in accordance to the rotation list?

Answer (score 0):

### Building the rotated list

#### Method one

Say you have a sequence of numbers such as:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

and you want to rotate them by `3` to the left like this:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2]
```

Notice that the first three numbers are shifted by `+3` from the original while the remaining two numbers are shifted by `-5` from the original.  Do you notice a pattern here?

The key thing to notice is that `-5` is just `+3 - 8`, where `8` is the length of the list.  In other words, the numbers undergo *an additive shift followed by a modulo operation*:

```
new_i = (old_i - shift) % length
```

Now, what you have is not a list of numbers, but a list of characters, but the difference is superficial: applying the same transformation to the *index* of the strings leads to the same effect of a rotation:

```
new_list[old_i] = old_list[new_i]
```

Then it's just a matter of repeating this operation for every element in the list.

(There is a slight subtlety with regards to the sign of `shift`; here, I use the convention that a positive shift is equivalent to rotating the values right.)

#### Method two

Another way is to think of a list rotation as a two step operation:

1. First you break up the list `old_list` into two parts: `left_half` and `right_half`.
2. Then you join them back together as `right_half + left_half`.

The main question here is: where do you break the list?  It is again related to the amount you want to shift in a simple way:

```
break_index = shift % length
```

The modulo is needed because a rotation by an integer multiple of `length` has no real effect on your list.

### Translating characters

To *use* the rotated list to translate a character (or a string of characters), you will need to find the location of the character in the original ordering:

```
index = old_list.index(character)
```

Then find the corresponding character in the rotated list:

```
translated_character = new_list[index]
```

### Optimizations

Building the `new_list` that contains the rotated alphabet is actually unnecessary for performing translations.  By performing some algebraic transformations, one see that the translated characters can be directly computed from the original alphabet:

```
translated_character = old_list[(index - shift) % length]
```

Additionally, using the `index` method is inefficient: it's better to construct a dictionary to speed up the lookups.

Comment: But how would I rotate the user inputted list in accordance to the master list such as: ["R", "U", "O"], with a rotation of 1. It should become ["Q", "V", "P"] according to the master list.

Comment: Added an explanation regarding the translation.  HTH